# Authentication for SaaS

Tags: php, authentication, saas

What would be recommended as an authentication solution for a Software-as-a-service product?

Specifically, my product would have clients that would typically have low information technology skills, potentially not even having an IT department within their organization. I would still like to have my application authenticate against their internal directory service (eDirectory, Active Directory, etc.). I don't want them, however, to have to open/forward ports (for instance, opening up port 636 so I can do LDAPS binds directly to their directory service).

One idea I had was to have an application installed on a server within their organization's network that would backconnect to my service. This would be a persistant socket. When I need to authenticate a user, I send the credentials via the socket (encrypted) - the application then performs a bind/whatever to authenticate against the directory service and replies with OK/FAIL.

What would you suggest? My goal here is to essentially have the client install an application within their network, with very little configuration or intervention.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought of installed applications as one-time payment products, whereas SaaS was handled remotely to the point where there was no client install.

Comment: The application is web-based and hosted remotely. However, I have a requirement that authentication be integrated with whatever directory service they may have.

Answer (score 3):

This vendor, [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com/), offers a service providing exactly what you are asking for: user authentication, user account management, with hookups to your customers’ on-premise directories (if need be, as is your case).

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, it'd be necessary to drop an agent on to their network which performs the authentication locally, then creates a signed token which "proves" to your SaaS app that it has done so; this can be passed on by the browser in a query string or form post (for example).

The agent might be an IIS-installable web app which can just authenticate the user and then direct them on to your servers in the cloud. This should not be a major hassle to install, but will create tech support issues. In particular, you need to get this component right first time, as users are not going to update it on a regular basis.

Making it work securely may be interesting.